# Persistently initiate reverse ssh tunnel from Android device

Tags: java, android, ssh

I need to have a number of android tablets initiate reverse ssh tunnels to my Linux server, as automatically and persistently as possible, whenever the  tablets find wifi. The tablets are not rooted (and they are actually running Amazon's Fire's OS).

I see mention of JSch in scripting something like this but I do not know what is involved in writing or implementing Java, whether it's something I can do on non-rooted devices, etc, so I'm trying to triage the effort needed for this.  Is the process essentially building my own app for Android? If I did that, is it something that could be launched once, or launched automatically on reboot, and run continuously forever, checking for wifi (attempting to open the tunnel) every minute or so?

Is there a reason there wouldn't be an app that can do this for me already (I cannot find it)? Is there an alternative to writing a Java app?  I speak other languages, like Python, and am trying to get a sense of how much work this will be, and which direction to go.

An ideal answer is a recipe or pre-made app to implement this, or clear directions how to do it, with answers to my questions above (in which case I'll post here the complete code and instructions when I've written it).

Answer (score -1):

The app Termux appears to be perfectly suited to all of this. Termux offers a Debian bash environment with many packages available, thus scriptability, ssh and sshd, etc etc just like I'm used to.  There are also Termux add-ons for API to tablet functions, and for auto-running scripts on tablet boot. It's also apparently easy to make icons on the desktop to run scripts bash/Python/etc scripts, and even to develop in C.

Our application is to be able to install with minimum fuss the ability on a large fleet of tablets to reverse ssh connect to a server, and then have that server do the rest of the configuration/installation, and regular tracking and maintenance.

This appears to be all doable, and maybe the reverse tunnel is easier than using a VPN for the same end.

(Update: this worked out brilliantly)